# Checkbox not persisting to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I use the following to display a checkbox linked to my model:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.GenerateAppendixA)
```

Based on various other user interactions on the page, sometimes I need to check this checkbox and then disable it.
I use the following jQuery to do this:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=GenerateAppendixA]').attr("checked", false);
$('input:checkbox[name=GenerateAppendixA]').attr("disabled", false);
```

However, when I check the box using jQuery the state of the boolean value in my model is always 'false'. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now that the ASP.NET MVC checkbox helper automatically generates a hidden field. Changing the value in the hidden field solved my issue.

```
<input name="GenerateAppendixA" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Regards